# IF NULL select data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the HTS "harmonized code" from two different tables.

STKMP purchased, STKMM Manufactured.

When I run my query, there are items that are missing the HTS from STKMP, I would like to replace NULLS
with the data on STKMM.  I have tried case when but it gives me no results.

```
Select distinct 
ltrim(rtrim(boldh.FEBOL#)) as BOL, 
--ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESCS#)) as ShipTo, 
--ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESNME)) as CustomerName, 
--ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FGCPO#)) as CustPO, 
--ltrim(rtrim(ocri.DDCSPI)) as CustLine, 
ltrim(rtrim(bold.FGCPT#)) as CustPart, 
ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESNME)) as CustName, 
ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESAD1)) as CustStreet, 
ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESAD2)) as CustStreet1, 
ltrim(rtrim(bolh.FESAD3)) as CustCityState,
ltrim(rtrim(stkmp.AWHARM)) as HTS,

case when STKMP.AWHARM is null then STKMM.AVHARM else stkmp.AWHARM end as HTTT,


ltrim(rtrim(V6CORG)) as COO,
ltrim(rtrim(awdes1)) as Descrip
--ltrim(rtrim([FGQSHO])) as QTY


FROM BOLH
left join bold on bolh.FEBOL# = bold.FGBOL# 
left join ocri on bold.FGORD# = ocri.DDORD# and bold.FGITEM = ocri.DDITM#
left join STKA on ocri.DDPART = stka.v6part
left join STKMP on stka.V6PART = STKMP.AWPART
left join STKMM on STKMP.AWPART = STKMM.AVPART
```

Thanks

Comment: *HTS "harmonized code"* might mean something to you.  But without a clear explanation, it probably won't mean much to other people.

Comment: And you need to provide a [mre] i.e. a small, simplified version which reproduces the problem, because as it stands your query looks OK.

Comment: Hello, you should mark an answer if your question is answered. You do it by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COALESCE ( expression [ ,...n ] )

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
COALESCE(STKMP.AWHARM, stkmp.AWHARM) AS HTTT
```

Alternatively, to see if you got some issues with your joins and/or both values are null you could take it one step further, like this.

```
COALESCE(STKMP.AWHARM, stkmp.AWHARM, 'Both values are NULL') AS HTTT
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, there are few more other options are there.

By using **ISNULL**

```
SELECT ISNULL(STKMP.AWHARM, stkmp.AWHARM) AS HTTT
```

By Using **IIF Statement**

```
SELECT IIF(STKMP.AWHARM IS NOT NULL,STKMP.AWHARM,stkmp.AWHARM) AS HTTT
```